# Upgrading Debian Jessie to Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, debian-jessie, debian-stretch

I followed [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch) tutorial but failed.

I got a lot of `PHP not found found` errors after update/upgrade commands, but I continued hoping Stretch would replace the PHP stuff.

Now `sudo apt-get update` gives following errors:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
112695A0E562B32A
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
648ACFD622F3D138
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`sudo apt-get update` gives following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.43-1+0~20200703.7+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-doc_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-common_76+0~20200511.26+debian8~1.gbpc9beb6_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php-pear/php-pear_1.10.8+submodules+notgz-1+0~20190219091008.9+jessie~1.gbp1a209a_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libidn2-0 libpcre3 libssl-doc libssl-dev libssl1.1 openssl libicu65 libxml2 php-common php7.3-intl php7.3-readline php7.3-mysql php7.3-bcmath php7.3-gd php7.3-xml php7.3-opcache php7.3-curl php7.3-json php7.3-cgi php7.3-bz2
  php7.3-mbstring php7.3-zip php7.3-cli libapache2-mod-php7.3 php7.3-common php-pear php7.3
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libidn2-0 amd64 2.2.0-2+0~20200302.4+debian8~1.gbpf85c2e [128 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libidn2-0 amd64 2.2.0-2+0~20200302.4+debian8~1.gbpf85c2e
  HttpError404
Get:2 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libpcre3 amd64 2:8.43-1+0~20200703.7+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f [339 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libpcre3 amd64 2:8.43-1+0~20200703.7+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f
  HttpError404
Get:3 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libssl-doc all 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f [1775 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libssl-doc all 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f
  HttpError404
Get:4 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f [1802 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f
  HttpError404
Get:5 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f [1550 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f
  HttpError404
Get:6 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main openssl amd64 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f [834 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main openssl amd64 1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f
  HttpError404
Get:7 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libicu65 amd64 65.1-1+0~20200223.8+debian8~1.gbp519cf3 [8453 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libicu65 amd64 65.1-1+0~20200223.8+debian8~1.gbp519cf3
  HttpError404
Get:8 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libxml2 amd64 2.9.9+dfsg-1+0~20200226.5+debian8~1.gbp3b6674 [730 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libxml2 amd64 2.9.9+dfsg-1+0~20200226.5+debian8~1.gbp3b6674
  HttpError404
Get:9 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php-common all 2:76+0~20200511.26+debian8~1.gbpc9beb6 [16.0 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php-common all 2:76+0~20200511.26+debian8~1.gbpc9beb6
  HttpError404
Get:10 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-intl amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 [124 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-intl amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1
  HttpError404
Get:11 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-readline amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 [12.2 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-readline amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1
  HttpError404
Get:12 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-mysql amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 [118 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-mysql amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1
  HttpError404
Get:13 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-bcmath amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 [15.2 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-bcmath amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1
  HttpError404
Get:14 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-gd amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 [27.4 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3-gd amd64 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1

Get:27 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3 all 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 [44.1 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.3 all 7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1
  HttpError404
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.2.0-2+0~20200302.4+debian8~1.gbpf85c2e_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.43-1+0~20200703.7+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-doc_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1g-1+0~20200421.17+debian8~1.gbpf6902f_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/i/icu/libicu65_65.1-1+0~20200223.8+debian8~1.gbp519cf3_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.9+dfsg-1+0~20200226.5+debian8~1.gbp3b6674_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-common_76+0~20200511.26+debian8~1.gbpc9beb6_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-intl_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-readline_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-mysql_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-bcmath_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-gd_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-xml_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-opcache_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-curl_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-json_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-cgi_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-bz2_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-mbstring_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-zip_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-cli_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/libapache2-mod-php7.3_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3-common_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php-pear/php-pear_1.10.8+submodules+notgz-1+0~20190219091008.9+jessie~1.gbp1a209a_all.deb  HttpError404

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.3/php7.3_7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1_all.deb  HttpError404
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#deb http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie main
#deb-src http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie main

#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

#jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
#deb http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie-updates main
#deb-src http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie-updates main

#jessie-backports, previously on backports.debian.org
#deb http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie-backports main
#deb-src http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie-backports main

#deb http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/debian/ virtualmin-jessie main
#deb http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/debian/ virtualmin-universal main

#ruti
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#ruti2
#deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy non-free
#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates non-free

#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

#Only these are uncommented below
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

`cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

My goal is upgrading Debian 8 to 10, but first step is upgrading to 9. I would be glad if you can help me!

Comment: You might need to install the 'debian-keyring' package first, see https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKeyring#Via_the_Debian_Archive (A sidenote, because you are coming from Jessie: If you do not want to work with systemd in the future, you could upgrade to Devuan instead:

Comment: how do I install the keyrings? apt-get debian-keyring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting php.list under sources.list.d/ worked.